# Mysql creating relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, typeorm

I'm stuck on finding a solution please help me out. Let me explain,i want to create relationships whereby a **car can have many drivers** but also **a driver can drive many cars**,**furthermore a car can have only one active driver**.I want to be able to query for a car to see all drivers that have driven that particular car and also be able to query for a driver to show a list of cars he/she has driven.Currently i have created many to many for the table cars and drivers but i also want to implement for the active driver part.

Comment: A car is 'logged; out to a driver for a period?

Comment: Something like that @P.Salmon

Comment: This looks like a rental model if so a transaction table containing booking details might be appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Create an intersection table to support the many-to-many relationship and add a column to that table to hold an indicator for the active relationship and effective start/end date columns